# Is it grammatically correct and natural to say 'This dress IS amazing on you'?

Tags: collocations

I know we can say "This dress **looks** amazing on you." but can we also say "This dress **is** amazing on you"?

I have always come across the verb 'to look' in reference to clothes. I wonder whether one can use the verb 'to be' here and sound natural and correct.

Answer (score 2):

> This dress is amazing on you.

is standard and not uncommon. Many people will be more likely to use "looks", but the meaning is roughly the same here.

"Looks" simply explicitly comments on the visual appearance of the dress. Saying "this dress is amazing on you" likely also refers to visual appearance, but it could be a more general statement. For a contrived example, if someone were obligated to wear a dress with the logo of their rival sports team, it might be "amazing" in the sense of being surprising or unexpected.

In most cases however, the meaning is the same either way. "Looks" is slightly less direct, which can be a social subtlety when discussing another's appearance.

Comment: It would be more common to say "That dress is/looks amazing on you." assuming that the lady is actually wearing the dress. You might use "this" if you are holding the dress and know that it looks amazing on her because you've seen her in it before.

Comment: @ColleenV I agree, but it could go either way. I was just restating the sentence from the question.

Comment: looks and is are semantically the same here.